# Contact recipient different than UID

Tags: emails

Is there any way to make that Drupal 7 built-in contact form sends the emails to a different address than the one of the UID 1?

Comment: Do you mean sending an email to the user #1 using an email address different from the one registered for that account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under admin/structure/contact/edit/1 you can add or remove any e-mail address(es) you want from the "recipients" box.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I have no idea how did I miss that! :S

Answer (score 0):

[Private Message](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) allows you to send messages to users registers on the site. Its a very robust module which integrates pretty well with notifications and rules. It also has a bunch of related modules to extend the core module functionality.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I have been looking for...